# Why doesn't this RegExp work and which notation is more standards compliant?

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

*Disclaimer*: I realize asking "Why doesn't my regular expression work" is pretty amateur.

I have looked at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), though I'm just plain struggling.  I have a url (as a string) and what I want is to replace the placeholders (i.e. `{objectID}` and `{queryTerm}`

For a while now, I've been making attempts like this:

```
var _serviceURL = "http://my-server.com/rest-services/someObject/{objectID}/entries?term={queryTerm}";

var re1 = new RegExp("/{([A-Za-z])+}","gi");  
var re2 = new RegExp("/{([A-Za-z]+)}+","gi");  
var re3 = new RegExp("/{([A-Za-z])+}","gi");  
var re4 = new RegExp("/({[A-Za-z]+})+","gi");  
var re5 = new RegExp("({[A-Za-z]+})+","gi");  
var re6 = new RegExp("({[A-Za-z]}+)*","g");  
var re6a = new RegExp("({([a-z]+)})+","gi");  

var re7 = /{([^}]+)}/g;

var tokens =  re6A.exec(_serviceURL);
if (null != tokens.length ){
    for(i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
        var t = tokens[i];
        console.log("tokens[i]: " + t);
    }            
}
else {
    console.log("RegEx fail...")
}
```

`re6a` above produces an array like this upon execution:

```
tokens: Array[3]
    0: "{objectID}"
    1: "{objectID}"
    2: "objectID"
```

Related to the scenario above:

1. Why is it I'm never getting the `queryTerm` ?
2. Does the RegExp 'i' (ignore case) flag mean I can list a character class like [a-z] and also capture [A-Z] ?
3. Which method of constructing a RegExp object is better?  `...new RegExp(...);` or `var regExp = /{([^}]+)}/g;` .  In terms of "what's better", what I mean is cross-browser compatibility and as similar to other RegEx implementations (if I'm learning RegEx, I want to get the most value I can out of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the RegExp `i` (ignore case) flag mean I can list a character class like `[a-z]` and also capture `[A-Z]`?

Yes, it'll capture them all.

> Which method of constructing a RegExp object is better? `new RegExp(...)` or `var regExp = /{([^}]+)}/g;`? In terms of "what's better", what I mean is cross-browser compatibility and as similar to other RegEx implementations (if I'm learning RegEx, I want to get the most value I can out of it).

You should definitely use the literal notation.
It gets compiled once at runtime, instead of every time you use it.
They're both equally cross browser compatible.

---

All that said, I'd use this:

```
_serviceURL.match(/[^{}]+(?=})/g);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CAugU/

---

Here's an explanation of the above regex:

```
[    opens the character set
 ^    negates the set. Will only match whatever is NOT in these brackets
 {}   match anything that is NOT a curly brace
]    close the character set
+    match that as many times as possible
(?=  ascertain that it is possible to match the following here (won't be included in the match, this is called a lookahead)
 }    match a curly brace
)    close the lookahead
```

Comment: Sorry, Joseph.  How about the `queryTerm` ?

Comment: @BrianL. - Check out the fiddle I just added.

Comment: That jsFiddle is great, I didn't realize they offer Firebug Lite inside the runner.  Thanks for breaking down the RegEx interpretation as well.  I went back to the docs and realized `^` has a different meaning inside a character set.  Since the expression matches "anything that is NOT a curly brace" , how does it know where to start?

Comment: @BrianL. - When the `^` appears at the beginning of a character set, it serves a different purpose: it negates the set. See my added explanation above.

Comment: @BrianL. - without the lookahead, it'll also match what's before the `{`: http://jsfiddle.net/CAugU/1/

Comment: Joeseph, thank you for the clear description of the operators and for forcing me to take a second look at their result given different invocation  (i.e. `^` with character class vs. not).  Here's my fork of the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brilong87/qx8Uh/

Answer (score 1):

As you're going to replace the placeholders, it seems more natural to use `replace` rather than `match`, for example:

```
var _serviceURL = "http://my-server.com/rest-services/someObject/{objectID}/entries?term={queryTerm}"

var values = {
    objectID: 1234,
    queryTerm: "hello"
}

var result = _serviceURL.replace(/{(.+?)}/g, function($0, $1) {
    return values[$1]
})
```

yields `http://my-server.com/rest-services/someObject/1234/entries?term=hello`